# Creating a magazine style gallery in JS

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a magazine style gallery which can fetch a number of JPGS (18) and render them in 2 divs. A Left and right button would then be used to load the next 2 pages. The first page would be the front-over which would be closed. Then afterwards the pages would be side by side like a spread.

I have created the following which is semi working, it loads in a list of JPGs and the next button pushes the image to the div and then iterates. The main issue is that when pressing the next button to change the page its iterating 1 at a time instead of changing to the next 2 pages.

I tried to change the `+1` to a `+2` in the `for` loop but it loads the first 2 page spread fine, then the rest it only iterates 1 page at a time.

Could anyone give me some advice on how this can be improved & change 2 pages at a time?

Here is a codePen to make this a bit clearer:

https://codepen.io/nolimit966/pen/JVoPJq

Thank you

```js
 var pages = [
    {"name":"img1", "src":"images/1.jpg"},
    {"name":"img2", "src":"images/2.jpg"},
    {"name":"img3", "src":"images/3.jpg"},
    {"name":"img4", "src":"images/4.jpg"},
    {"name":"img5", "src":"images/5.jpg"},
    {"name":"img6", "src":"img/prod-6.png"},
    {"name":"img7", "src":"img/prod-7.png"},
    {"name":"img8", "src":"img/prod-8.png"},
    {"name":"img9", "src":"img/prod-9.png"},
  ];

imgIndex = 0;

document.getElementById("image2").src = pages[0].src;

document.getElementById("nextBtn").addEventListener("click", function(){

  var page2 = document.getElementById("image1")

    if(pages.length > imgIndex+1){
      imgIndex++;
    // page1.classList.toggle('is-active');
      document.getElementById("image1").style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById("image1").src = pages[imgIndex].src;
      document.getElementById("image2").src = pages[imgIndex+1].src;
    } else {
     console.log("its zero");
      imgIndex = 0;
    }

});
```

```html
<button id="prevBtn">Previous</button>
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>

<div id="container">
  
 <div id="page1">
   <img src="" id="image1" alt="" style="display:none;"/>
 </div>

 <div id="page2">
<img src="" id="image2" alt=""/>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why would `+2` cause issues? What kind of issues? Also, why bother create another image gallery / carousel when there are countless free ones? For learning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add two to the index number each time when index number is **not zero** (not cover page)

When current page is at cover page (imgIndex=0)

imgIndex 0 -> 1: Display imgIndex 1 and 2

When current page is not at cover page (imgIndex>0)

imgIndex 1 -> 3: Display imgIndex 3 and 4

imgIndex 3 -> 5: Display imgIndex 5 and 6

So instead of

```
imgIndex++;
```

Try this

```
if(imgIndex == 0){
    imgIndex++;
}else {
    imgIndex += 2;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help - thats really appreciated